# Parsing a text file and inserting values into a datatable

Tags: vb.net, parsing, text-files

I have a text file which contains strings without a splitter:

```
881234567812345000000ABCD
998765432112345000000WXYZ <- 2nd line
```

I need to split these strings into columns and insert them into a `DataTable`:

```
ID  | AccountNo | AreaNo | LeaveZero | Letters
=====================================
88  | 12345678  |  12345 | 000000    | ABCD
99  | 87654321  |  12345 | 000000    | WXYZ
```

How can this be achieved in VB.NET?

=============================

**UPDATE**

Here's some of my code. I'm using DevExpress to build the GUI:

```
Imports DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon
Imports System.IO
Imports DevExpress.Spreadsheet

Public Class Form1

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Private Sub BarButtonItem1_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles BarButtonItem1.ItemClick
        Dim fd As New OpenFileDialog
        If fd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.Text = fd.FileName
            import(fd.FileName)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub import(ByRef pathname As String)
        Dim txtLine As String = ""
        Dim newline As String = ""

        Using stream As New StreamReader(pathname)
            For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(pathname)
                txtLine = txtLine & String.Format("{0} {1}", line.Substring(0, 2), line.Substring(2, 20)) & vbNewLine
            Next

            dt.Columns.Add("recordID")
            dt.Columns.Add("accountNo")
            dt.Columns.Add("reserved")
            dt.Columns.Add("billNo")

            newline = stream.ReadLine

            While newline IsNot Nothing
                Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
                For i As Integer = 0 To 3 Step 1
                    'dr(i) = newline.Substring(0, 2 + i)
                Next
                dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            End While
        End Using
        GridControl1.DataSource = dt
        MemoEdit1.Text = txtLine
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What is the logic and what is your effort so far?

Comment: So, those strings are automatically generated by Bank into one single text file.. I need to translate them, so I could insert them into my database.. I just updated my question with my code..

Comment: Use the `TextFieldParser`, important are following two lines: `parser.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.FixedWidth
    parser.FieldWidths = {2, 8, 5, 6, 4}`

Comment: I've tested it.. but it only read the last line.. and, how do i put them into datatable?

Comment: You need a loop, f.e. `While parser.PeekChars(1) IsNot Nothing Dim fields = parser.ReadFields()...`. You don't know how to add DataRows to a DataTable? Sorry, there are plenty of tutorials out there